# Run groovy test in IntelliJ on Linux

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, groovy

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA community edition, and I created a groovy unit test for my java class `Polynomial`, when I attempt to run the test, I get "Groovyc: unable to resolve class `groovy.util.GroovyTestCase`"

[image]

I correctly marked the test/ directory as tests, so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> created the unit test in the correct directory. How can I get this test to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so You need to add groovy*.jar in External Library of project.

Select project and press F12, and select "Modules", in this window is possible to add groovy library.

Another option is to add external library when to create new IDEA project.

Comment: I did this in the dependencies section, still have the same error on rebuild though.

Comment: Please, remember that add all dependencies of groovy. When to downlod groovy SDK add all jars from "lib" folder. http://groovy-lang.org/download.html